# WPF HelixTookit Viewport3DX Vector limit

Tags: wpf, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

I am trying to load point data into Viewport3DX.
I am loading coordinates that are in EPSG:7855. When loading data map is empty almost like nothing happen. I feel like I am hitting some kind of a Vector limit as when I try to load test data it works ok.

```
    public EffectsManager EffectsManager { get; }

    public MapViewModel()
    {
        this.EffectsManager = new DefaultEffectsManager();
    }

    private PointGeometry3D _pointGeometry;
    public PointGeometry3D PointGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            //return this._pointGeometry;
            var vc = new Vector3Collection();
            var id = new IntCollection();
            
            // Test Data
            vc.Add(new Vector3(10, 19, 10));
            id.Add(0);
            vc.Add(new Vector3(19, 10, 10));
            id.Add(1);
            vc.Add(new Vector3(15, 15, 10));
            id.Add(2);
            
            // Real data (**issue here**)
            // vc.Add(new Vector3(693409, 6088877, 10));
            // id.Add(0);
            // vc.Add(new Vector3(693409, 6088606, 10));
            // id.Add(1);
            // vc.Add(new Vector3(694131, 6088877, 10));
            // id.Add(2);

            var g = new PointGeometry3D { Positions = vc, Indices = id };
            return g;
        }
}
```

XML Code

```
<hx:Viewport3DX ShowCoordinateSystem="True" BackgroundColor="#FF88AACD"
                  x:Name="HelixView" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" EffectsManager="{Binding EffectsManager}">
    <hx:AmbientLight3D Color="#363636" />
    <hx:PointGeometryModel3D Geometry="{Binding PointGeometry}" Size="5 5" Color="Bisque"/>
</hx:Viewport3DX>
```

The issue appears to be only with *helixtoolkit.sharpdx.core.wpf* as *helixtoolkit.core.wpf* with Point3D objects are displaying data correctly. I switch to shaprdx as I read that performance is better since it uses more GPU.

Real result
[image]

Test data result
[image]

Comment: Do you have the code on how you load the EPSG:7855 data? Particularly on generate the Point geometry 3D.

Comment: I am reading it from DataTable which I am getting from Postgres database using Npgsql nuget. "CODE"

      await using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(databaseConnection))
      {
        await using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
          await conn.OpenAsync();
          command.AllResultTypesAreUnknown = true;
          NpgsqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
          message.Load(reader);
          await reader.CloseAsync();
          await conn.CloseAsync();
          return message;
        }
      }

Comment: Inside the DataTable geometry is stored as a NetTopologySuite.Geometry.Point

var point = new Point(wktReader.Read(geom).Coordinate.X, wktReader.Read(geom).Coordinate.Y, wktReader.Read(geom).Coordinate.Z);

Comment: Have you checked whether the geometry 3d contains all the points loaded from the database?

Comment: Yep, all are there, they are just not showing on the map. Same happen even on the given example with 3 points in.

Comment: But your screenshot shows the 3 points are rendering correctly?

Comment: Probably you need to scale your data. Or your camera settings are not covering the points

Comment: Might be something to do with the camera. In helixtoolkit.core.wpf I zoom to points by double-clicking the middle mouse button, for sharpdx doesn't seem like it does the trick. But I thought ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" will do it anyway right?